# How to set existing text from a variable within a function? Python Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, textinput

I created a function that opens a log file, and saves it to a variable named `loginfo`. In my kivy file, I have a TextInput widget. I tried setting the existing `text:` to `root.loginfo`.

The `loginfo` needs to be within a function because I am using the kivy's Clock to re-read the log file.

Python file:

```
class Tasks(Screen):
    logginfo = ObjectProperty()

    def reset_text(dt):
        with open('logtest.log', 'r') as file:
            loginfo = file.read()

    Clock.schedule_once(reset_text, -1)
```

Kivy file:

```
<Tasks>:
    name: 'task'
    logginfo: logginfo
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "TASKS"

        TextInput:
            id: logginfo
            text: root.loginfo
```

The problem started occurring when I created the `reset_text(dt)` function and `kivy.clock`. Without the function, and just the contents of it, the textinput box displays the logtest.log file's contents correctly.

When I run the script, it gives me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`. I'm confused and stuck, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your reset_text function, you should explicitly change the text of your TextInput (the one with `id: logginfo` at the moment). Also, can you post more of your code - like where you define your App class and such? If we can copy/paste your code to debug it ourselves you'll get better answers as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Erik  how can I explicitly change the text from TextInput from my python file? logginfo.text?  for my App class, I use Builder.load_file to load the kivy file. Then within the build function, I just return the kivy file.

Comment: Close - to reference your TextInput you have to reference it using something like `App.get_running_app().root.ids['logginfo'].text = loginfo`. Try putting that in your `reset_text` function.

Comment: @Erik what do you mean when you write "Close - "? When I add that line and run, I get  ` KeyError: 'logginfo'`

Comment: I meant like you're close to having the right solution. If you get that KeyError, I know what's wrong but I need to see more of your code. Can you edit your answer to have a more complete kv file?

Comment: Or if your entire kv file is simply that TextInput, then the `root` attribute of `App.get_running_app()` already refers to your TextInput. So you can just use `App.get_running_app().root.text = loginfo`

Comment: In your Python code, you have a property named `logginfo` (with 2 `g`), but in `reset_text` you are setting `loginfo` (with 1 `g`), and in kivy your also have `loginfo`.  Perhaps they should be the same?

Comment: @JohnAnderson no, logginfo is the id of the textinput widget. loginfo is the log file

Comment: @Erik i edited my post. idk if revealing that the class is a screen would help. I tried the line you provided. This time no error, but nothing appears in the textinput widget. (yes, logtest.log does have text in it) btw, thanks alot for your replies and assistance.

Comment: Then what is `logginfo = ObjectProperty()`

Comment: @JohnAnderson hmm that question is making me feel dumb haha.... I seen a video tutorial on youtube where the instructor said ObjectProperty is used to interact with kivy widgets (from kivy file) from the python file. So my logic is, without the object property, I would not be able to interact with the widgets I created in the kv file. But I just removed ObjectProperty from a different part of the script, and it doesn't seem to effect anything at all... I must've misinterpreted the correct use of objectproperty.

Comment: The problem started occurring when I created the `reset_text(dt)` function. Without the function, and just the contents of it, the textinput box displays the logtest.log file's contents correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete example to do what you want to do. You'll have to modify it to integrate it with your code, but my intention here was to show you the proper way to achieve this and let your work with it yourself.

Note how I'm using Clock.schedule_interval instead of schedule once. The `1` in the schedule_interval is the time between calling the `self.reset_text` function in seconds. Note how in the `reset_text` function I can refer to my base widget in my `kv` file using `self.root` (the GridLayout), then I can get the TextInput (since I gave it an id) by doing `self.root.ids['my_text_input']`

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.reset_text, 1) # Check if log has changed once a second
        return GUI

    def reset_text(self, *args):
        with open("logtest.log", "r") as f:
            self.root.ids['my_text_input'].text = f.read()

MainApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
GridLayout:
    # This is the 'root' widget when referenced in python file
    cols: 1
    TextInput:
        id: my_text_input
```

Comment: Wow, this makes a lot of sense. This works when I put my_text_input in the root BoxLayout, but doesn't work when I put it in a screen that is called by a screenmanager within the root... which also makes sense since it's not in the root. So in my `reset_text` function, is there a different path i can specify? for example, `self.root.screenmanage.thescreen.ids['my_text_input'].text = f.read()` what would be proper way of locating the screen?

Comment: You've got the right logic! You need to give your Screen an id. Then you can do `self.root.ids['my_screen_id'].ids['my_text_input']` to reference the text input in that screen. This works because your screen is in the root widget, and your text input is in your screen widget. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I have a video on this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU8jjgzH1LE&t=358s just fyi!