# Kivy Framework: Label text does not update when using ScreenManager

Tags: python, kivy

i'm just started using Kivy. i'm making an application that uses multiple screens. Screens are selected by buttons in the upper part of interface. Each screen represent different functionality of program. Now here come the problem:
i have created a function that changes the Label text on screen 1. Function seems to work properly but Label text does not change when "Change Label button is pressed. What could be the problem? i've looked for a similar answers but they are not related, everything should work AFAIK. Here the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Display(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Screen_One(Screen):

    mytext = "Initial Text"

    def change_text(self,input):
    self.mytext = input

class Screen_Two(Screen):
    pass

class Screen_Three(Screen):
    pass

class MyNewApp(App):
    def build(self):
    return Display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyNewApp().run()
```

And .kv file

```
<Display>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: '48dp'
        Button:
            text: 'One'
            on_release: sm.current = 'screen_one'  
        Button:
            text: 'Two'
            on_release: sm.current = 'screen_two' 
        Button:
            text: 'Three'
            on_release: sm.current = 'screen_three'  
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        Screen_One:
        Screen_Two:
        Screen_Three:

<Screen_One>:
    name: 'screen_one'      
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: 'Change Label'
            on_press:root.change_text("New Text")
        Button:
            text: 'For Later'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                text: root.mytext



<Screen_Two>:
    name: 'screen_two'      
    Button:
        text: 'Two'

<Screen_Three>:
    name: 'screen_three'
    Button:
        text: "Three"
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: You set the text when you app starts with `text: root.mytext` but that doesn't know when `root.mytext` changes. You need to change the text of the label, not the txt of `root.mytext`. Very similar to my answer here (ignore the part about the clock): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597139/how-to-set-existing-text-from-a-variable-within-a-function-python-kivy/54598272#54598272

Comment: Thank you Erik. I will try. Your video is amazing.I also just found another solution - StringProperty. If i use mytext = StringProperty("Initial Text") then everything works properly and Label changes!

Comment: Thanks :) Nice work finding multiple solutions!